# Connect mssql to android app

Tags: android, sql-server

I'm trying to connect my android app to mssql database. But I got an exception when im trying to connect. I have checked in debug mode and goes from `Class.forName`  to the exception catch
here is my code .

```
protected void onStart() {
    try  
    { 
         // Load the SQLServerDriver class, build the 
         // connection string, and get a connection 
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
         String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx\\xxxxx:1433;" + 
                                 "database=xxxx;" + 
                                 "user=xxxx;" + 
                                 "password=*****"; 
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
         System.out.println("Connected."); 

         // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.  
         String SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxxxx";  
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
         TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv.setText((CharSequence) rs);


         // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.  
         while (rs.next())  
         {  
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));  
         }


    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats simply not possible, Android suffer from a limit of bandwidth so it can't talk to any external databases, but what you could do is , to create a simple web page (php) that return what you need from MySQL database and parse it as an xml file or maybe JSON because it's better now, then you can call this php page from your android application and get the JSON file.

this is a tuto explain this very well:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to MSSQL from Android app like that. You should create a web service for handling database requests. Then you can call that webservice from your app.